# Passing HTML to the response object

Tags: theming, 8

I had this piece of code in a module developed for some previous version of Drupal 8.

```
protected function getOutput() {
    $content = $this->buildContent();
    //print_r($content);
    $page = array(
      '#theme' => 'html',
      '#page_object' => new Html(render($content)),
    );
    $rendered_page = render($page);
    return $rendered_page;
}
```

Now, in the present beta release, it shows this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\hardcopy\Plugin\Html' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalbeta7\modules\custom\hardcopy\src\Plugin\HardcopyFormatBase.php on line 175

Can someone tell me how to pass the HTML of the whole page in the response object?

Answer (score 2):

As D8 uses Symfony responses it's as simple as:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

...

$response = new Response(
  'Your HTML content here',
  Response::HTTP_OK,
  array('content-type' => 'text/html')
);

return $response;
```

See [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html) for more information.

Comment: I think this will be useful to me(will be trying). Can help me with this I have generated an array containing information related to a node by using this: ($content = $this->entityManager()->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId())->view($entity, 'copy');). But I want to  get rid of comment section present in the array. Any idea how to do so? Feeling bad I can't even upvote since I am novice over here

Comment: The comment output can be controlled per view mode/display. You can add your view mode and display configuration to your module and then hide the comment field there.